NextJS Mongo Database and Redis connection error in docker compose build
So I have a nextJS app which uses mongoDB and Redis.
I tried deploying the app using docker compose. In the build process of nextJS app while Generating static pages the nextJS tries connecting to redis and mongo to collect page data for static page builds, but the problem is that their container is not up and running at that moment!
Redis connection err:
42.85 [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis_pishrun
42.85     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
42.85     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17)


Mongo connection err:
73.84 MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo_pishrun
73.84     at _handleConnectionErrors (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:909:11)
73.84     at NativeConnection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:860:11) {
73.84   reason: TopologyDescription {
73.84     type: 'Unknown',
73.84     servers: Map(1) { 'mongo_pishrun:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
73.84     stale: false,
73.84     compatible: true,
73.84     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
73.84     localThresholdMS: 15,
73.84     setName: null,
73.84     maxElectionId: null,
73.84     maxSetVersion: null,
73.84     commonWireVersion: 0,
73.84     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
73.84   },
73.84   code: undefined,
73.84   digest: '2271496410'
73.84 }


here is my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  pishrun-next:
    container_name: pishrun-next
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENV_VARIABLE: ${ENV_VARIABLE}
        NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE}
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    networks:
      - shared_network
    depends_on:
      - mongo_pishrun
      - redis_pishrun


  mongo_pishrun:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo_pishrun
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongo_pishrun_data:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=Aa!23456
    networks:
      - shared_network

  redis_pishrun:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis_pishrun
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    networks:
      - shared_network
    volumes:
      - redis_pishrun_data:/data


volumes:
  mongo_pishrun_data:
    driver: local
  redis_pishrun_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  shared_network:
    external: true

And this is the docker file for the nextJS app
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .

ARG ENV_VARIABLE
ENV ENV_VARIABLE=${ENV_VARIABLE}
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE=${NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE}

RUN npm run build
CMD npm run start

What I have tried already:

Creating a shared network for the containers
Running redis and mongo containers separately and then building the netsJS container.
Adding network as build argument to use it in the build process docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build --build-arg NETWORK=shared_network 

It seems like the docker does not have access to any docker network while building? IDFK...

Correct, RUN instructions do not have access to any Docker networks while building.  It doesn't usually make sense to connect to databases while you're building an image.  (What happens if you deploy the same images, without rebuilding, to a new system that doesn't have the same data in its databases?)

Well, I found the solution. Maybe it's somewhat stupid but I used it in production.
At first I have to make clear that static data ain't usually stored in DB or if, they can be extracted out. So while building static pages (at least in my application) there is no need to connect to the data base.
And you guessed it:
    if (process.env.BUILD) this.redis = null // do not make connection
    else
      this.redis = new _Redis({
        host: redisHost,
        port: +redisPort,
        password: redisPassword,
      });

  if (process.env.BUILD) cachedMongo.promise = null;
    else
      cachedMongo.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
        console.log(
          '= MongoDB Connected!!!! ='
        );
        return mongoose;
      });


So as you see, I just removed the connecting part of Redis and mobgoDB in build process.
You also need to modify your build script like for the if checks to work!
//package.json
  "build": "BUILD=true next build",

I steel look forward for a better solution, but this works for now. <3
